# Simple Recurrence Questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science, recursion

$r$ is a real number, define a recurrence relationship for $A_n$

$$A_0 = 1\\
A_n = r\cdot A_{n-1}$$

Question: What is the value of $A_4$

1. $4(A{n-1})$
2. $r^4$
3. $1$
4. $4r$

*I've pretty much eliminated answer choice #4*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question:

You know that $a_0=1$ and that $a_n = ra_{n-1}$. Plugging in $n=1$ means that $a_1 = ra_{1-1}$. Can you now calculate $a_1$? You say that $A_4 = 4(A_n-1)$, but this is a bad answer. What, here, is the value of $n$? See, If you ask me "how old are you", and I answer $24 x + 23$, why is this answer wrong? Because I haven't told you what $x$ is, right? Same with this answer, you cannot say $A_4=4(A_n-1)$ if you don't tell me what $n$ is.

Comment: Okay so for #1 I think its just 1. For #2 I'm getting Tn=Tn−1+Tn−2. Does that look right?

Comment: Does $T_n = T_{n-1} + T_{n-2}$ hold for $n=6$? For #1, how can it just be $1$ if $a_1 = r\cdot a_0$? What is $a_0$, and if you plug in $a_0$, what is $a_1$?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not following how to solve these... I don't understand this stuff at all. Mind showing a step by step

Comment: I *am* showing you step by step. Look, if I say that $x = 5 \cdot a$ and $a=10$, what is the value of $x$? You MUST know that. Once you have that, now you have the same problem: $a_1 = x = r\cdot a_{1-1}$, and $a_{1-1} = a_0 = 1$. What is the value of $x$ (and, therefore, the value of $a_1$?

Comment: I understood x = 5*a that was 50 obviously. lol :P I have no idea what your talking about though when your writing the next line.

Comment: OK, so, if $x = r\cdot y$ and $y = 1$, what is the value of $x$?

Comment: The value is: r

Comment: I think I get this, is the answer for #1: 4(An−1) and the answer for #2 1+Tn−2

Comment: You don't get it yet. Yes, the value is $r$. Now, if from $x=r\cdot y$ and $y=1$, you can know that $x=r$, look at this: $a_1 = r\cdot a_{1-1}$, and $a_0 = 1$. What is the value of $a_1$?

Comment: The value is: r

Comment: OK, now you know the value of $a_1$. Now, knowing that $a_n = r\cdot a_{n-1}$, what is the formula for $a_2$ and what is the value of $a_2$?

Comment: Maybe I should write out what I'm thinking. If A0 = 1 then A1 = r * 0 = 0 + r * 1 + r * 2 + r * 3 = 6r which isn't an option.

Comment: The value is: a2 = 2r

Comment: I'm not trolling this is an online homework assignment that is due tomorrow at 11pm and I don't understand what's going on at all.

Comment: No, the value of $a_2$ is not $2r$. See, the value of $a_1$ is $r$, as you already said. Now, what is the formula for $a_2$, if you know that $a_n = r\cdot a_{n-1}$?

Comment: Is it just r^4?

Comment: Can you justify why it would be $r^4$?

Comment: No, I can't. My only justification is because we've gone through the other 3 answers and you told me they were wrong. lol

Comment: OK, then answer my previous question. Knowing that $a_n=r\cdot a_{n-1}$, what is the formula for $a_2$? You asked me to guide you step by step, so that is what I am doing.

Comment: I don't understand how we even got a1... -facepalm-

Comment: OK, now do this: you know that $a_n = r\cdot a_{n-1}$. What do you get when you set $n=1$?

Comment: A1 = r*0 = 0...

Comment: ^That doesn't equal r...

Comment: Aaa, now I see your problem. No, $n-1$ is a SUBSCRIPT! $a_{0}$ does not mean $a\cdot 0$, it means $a_0$ as in "the 0-th" value of the sequence! This means that you have a sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$ and so on. $a_n$ for $n=1$ is $a_1$, for example.

Comment: A0 = r * 1 = r (Okay I get that) Now what do I do with A1?

Comment: No, $a_0=1$, by definition.

Comment: I give up.. Math makes no sense.

Comment: The equation $a_n=r\cdot a_{n-1}$ means: "the $n$-th element of the sequence is equal to $r$ times the $n-1$-th element of the sequence." Do you understand that?

Comment: This question has gone on too long and we're getting nowhere... I edited out the other two question and I'm just gonna make a new thread for the remaining 2 questions...

Comment: I advise you to try and stick with me here, I think we may still get somewhere. Now: do you understand what $A_n = r\cdot A_{n-1}$ means? That it means that "the value of $A_n$, the $n$-th element of the sequence, is equal to $r$ times $A_{n-1}$, the $n-1$-th element"?

Comment: Yes I get that. Now what do I plugin for A1?

Comment: Well, $A_1$ is the first element of the sequence. This means it equals to $r$ times the zero-th element of the sequence. This means it equals to $r$ times $A_0$. You already know what $A_0$ is, right?

Comment: So An never increments? It's just the same thing 4 times in a row?

Comment: $A_n$ is a "general" expression. $A_n$ means "the $n$-th" value. It is like saying "the $n$-th largest country in the world". For $n=1$, this means "the largest country in the world", so Russia. For $n=2$, it means "the second largest", I presume that is Canada, and so on.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken. America is the largest country in the world sir.

Comment: Dude I'm giving up. I'm now resorting to trolling.

Comment: Try not to. Now, do you understand that from $A_n = r\cdot A_{n-1}$, if I insert $n=1$, I get the equation $A_1 = r\cdot A_0$?

Comment: If you give up, then delete your question. I will delete my answer, for the sake of clarity on the site.